# How to remove this "grey area" from the window corner in Kubuntu 20.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes

My OS is Kubuntu 20.04.

I got this ugly "grey area" on the top corner of window. No matter what theme I use, this "grey effect" remains there.

I've installed some themes from `System settings > Global themes > Get new global themes`. But all the themes show this same problem.

Can anyone please help me out removing this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with KDE, but look for composition setting and make sure it is enabled. That **might** help you.

Comment: @Ravexina, compositor is set to be enabled on startup. It does not work.

Comment: Does this problem persist when using open source driver for your gpu ?

Comment: What window is this? What is the application in use?

Answer (score 1):

> My OS is Kubuntu 20.04.
>
> I got this ugly "grey area" on the top corner of window. **No matter what theme I use**, this "grey effect" remains there.

Re. "*No matter what theme I use*", I don't see an ugly "grey area" with the Breeze, Breeze Dark, or Kubuntu Global Themes supplied with Kubuntu 20.04.

**No ugly grey area with default themes**

[image: Breeze Dark Global Theme]

Your image indicates you're using themes obtained from elsewhere, perhaps the [KDE Store](https://store.kde.org/). Please contact the developer(s) of those themes and ask that the issue be fixed.